# Нюансы при слиянии массивов

Tags: php

Подскажите что я не правильно делаю при слиянии массивов ?

пытаюсь соединить массивы array_merge($array1, $array2); но при слиянии уничтожаются ключи date и id_city

```
array(3) {
  ["2019-05-18"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2019-05-18"
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["id_city"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  ["2019-05-19"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2019-05-19"
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["id_city"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  ["2019-05-20"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2019-05-20"
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["id_city"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}

array(3) {
  ["2019-05-18"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  ["2019-05-19"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(9)
  }
  ["2019-05-20"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(8)
  }
}
```

Comment: Может быть надо посмотреть в __мануал__?

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите что я не правильно делаю при слиянии массивов ?

не читаете документацию.

Данная функция слияния вообще никак не обрабатывает вложенные массивы. Чтобы совместить вложенные вам потребуется [`array_merge_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

```
$a = ['x' => ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'v' => 10]];
$b = ['x' => ['c' => 3, 'v' => 20]];

$result = array_merge_recursive($a, $b);

print_r($result);
```

получим

```
Array (
    [x] => Array (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [v] => Array (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 20
            )
            [c] => 3
        )    
)
```

Согласно документации значения одинаковых ключей помещаются в массив. Если же вам их надо как-то преобразовать (сложить, например), то это необходимо сделать вручную. Обычно для подобных преобазований используют `array_map`, но можете воспользоваться и `array_walk` или простым циклом.

```
 array_walk($result, function(&$v){   $v['v'] = array_sum($v['v']); });
```

Comment: да я пробовал функцию array_merge_recursive()  но функция не суммирует ключи и по count  и отображает в поле count   не сумму а массив из нескольких значений ,  как это можно исправить ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник а с какой стати она должна суммировать?  вам надо просуммировать, васе пупкину вычесть, а я вообще умножить мб хочу. Слияние сам по себе не проводит никаких действий, если хотите описать некую логику, то сделать это придется вручную.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник дополнил ответ.